# What is a 'sparrow bath' and how do you do it in airport bathroom?

Tags: airports, hygiene

I read in [How to hide your bodily odors after a long flight?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20639/how-to-hide-your-bodily-odors-after-a-long-flight) that you can take a 'sparrow bath' to freshen in an airport bathroom when traveling.

How do you take the sparrow bath?

How do you freshen yourself?

What does it constitute?

Details please. I tried searching both on the web and Wikipedia and got nowhere about it. Please share/explain the procedure.

I am trying to figure out an exact procedure while the other question is related to more generic ideas. While the idea was shared therein, it wasn't explained there at all. Even now, we have just mere speculation of what the term might mean, so its inconclusive.

Comment: The term does not seem to be standard in English. Your query is probably best directed to the person who posted the answer using that term, in the form of a comment on that answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide your bodily odors after a long flight?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20639/how-to-hide-your-bodily-odors-after-a-long-flight)

Comment: @pnuts I'm not sure this would be on-topic at ELL. Sure, you can ask there what terms and phrases mean (unless they're easy to look up, in which case it's off-topic under the "general reference" clause). However, asking for detailed instructions on how to take such a bath is off-topic at ELL. Voting to leave open.

Comment: @pnuts  That is fair enough. Just wanted to discourage posting such questions at ELL.

Comment: @pnuts That would likely be fine, as long as the meaning of the term is not readily available in dictionaries, in which case it's closed as general reference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here is [a video of a sparrow taking a bath](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovMSvhQKAP8).  As you can see, it's basically splashing water from the basin over your face - which as a human, it may be worth extending to splashing over parts of your body, but is basically just slang for a quick 'freshen up'.

To clarify, to freshen up - that is, wipe off some sweat, rub dust off your body - kind of like a wash by hand without removing your clothes (although you might also change clothes separately in a cubicle, you wouldn't do this by the basin in the bathroom).

Comment: Does this add anything to the 8 answers to the other question?

Comment: @phoog well the other question didn't explain what a  sparrow bath was, which is what the OP is asking. No?

Comment: I was under the impression it was something more. As what you had shared, I had already 'sparrow bathed' in an airport, just didn't know the term :)

Comment: @shirish - I'm not convinced it's a standard term; it's more likely just a colorful turn of phrase by the author of the original article. It's much more common for someone to say that they "splashed some water on their face."

Comment: I haven't come across the term before, but it is a very evocative turn of phrase if you've ever watched sparrows washing themselves in a pool of water. I like it.

Comment: Probably it's a figure of speech in some language which is not English. In German you say Katzenwäsche which is like cat's bath...

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas a web search suggests strongly that it definitely is not a standard phrase in English, though I'm rather partial to Nobody's hypothesis that it is a standard phrase in some other language. Perhaps the poster of the answer to the other question in which the phrase was used will weigh in (I believe it was Gagravarr).

Comment: I'v always called this a "PTA" bath. From my grandfather.  It's not a nice acronym, but it conveys the meeting very well. (Privates, Tits, and Armpits). It's meant as a "when you don't have a choice but want/need to freshen up a little bit" a "sparrow bath" is the same thing, but without sounding quite so rude.

Comment: @pnuts Not sure I understand? The question was about airports.  I mentioned bathrooms and cubicles within, I expect anyone reading it would presume I'm talking about the airport mentioned in the Q.

Comment: Again, the tag is for the question.  An answer is a response to the question, and which in this case has even been accepted by the OP.